# Selenium C# - why is verbose logging for Chrome not working with this code?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to have all logging from Chrome's console, so I am using the code below.
However, still only Warning/Severe level logs are captured.

```
ChromeDriverService driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(driverPath);
driverService.EnableVerboseLogging = true;

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("disable-infobars");
options.AddUserProfilePreference("credentials_enable_service", false);
options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);

RemoveWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, options);

// do stuff here to generate console logs

var logs = driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser);
foreach (var log in logs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(log.Level + " - " + log.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `LogType.Browser` is empty since you never tell the driver to record them.

Add this to your options and see if it helps:

```
options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Browser, LogLevel.All);
```